# position is an array in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
<div className="example" style="top:10;left:10"></div>  //array 1
<div className="example" style="top:100;left:100"></div>  //array 2
<div className="example" style="top:145;left:101"></div>  //array 3
<div className="example" style="top:120;left:150"></div>  //array 4
<div className="example" style="top:145;left:160"></div>  //array 5
<div className="example" style="top:10;left:120"></div>  //array 6
<div className="example" style="top:15;left:100"></div>  //array 7


<script>
var x = $(".example")[0].position();  //array 1 [0]
alert("Top: " + x.top + " Left: " + x.left);
</script>
```

I need to get the position of a certain div

but when I run the code I get error

**VM163:1 Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].position is not a function(…)**

Comment: `$(".example").eq(0).position()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: http://jsbin.com/liliwarogo/1/edit

```
var x = $($(".example")[0]).position();  //array 1 [0]
alert("Top: " + x.top + " Left: " + x.left);
```

Basically, if you do `$(".example")[0]` it's not a jQuery element anymore, so `position()` doesn't exists. I wrapped everything up in jQuery again, to get the `position()` function.

Of course, the optimal solution would be something like this: `$(".example:eq(0)").position()`

Comment: I absolutely agree, I wanted to explain why `$(".example")[0].position()` doesn't work - that making `[0]` you're not operating with jQuery anymore. `$(".example").eq(0)` is of course the best solution, but it doesn't explain why the original approach didn't work. Besides, I personally prefer `$(".example:eq(0)")`. I've updated my original answer accordingly to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

This solution only use JavaScript.

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example")[0].getBoundingClientRect();
alert("Top: " + x.top + " Left: " + x.left);
```

Here is the [Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/mapawujeye/edit?html,js,output) example